# Is it probable that a penetration tester can eventually become a good malware analyst?

Tags: professional-education, career

Would it be logical for a pen tester who knows scripting and how viruses/malware are made to apply for a job as a malware analyst? Would this give him/her an edge at all? Or not really.

Comment: It's going to really depend on what type of pentester you are. The skillset is wide, and not all skills intersect with malware analytics.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I am currently in transition from a primary penetration-testing skillset towards a Data Forensics and Incident Response (DFIR) skillset which includes Malware Analysis.

My background in network engineering has helped me with tools such as [Malcom](https://github.com/tomchop/malcom), for analyzing C2, but also with configurations of automated malware analysis solutions, such as Palo Alto Networks WildFire/AutoFocus as well as FireEye and LastLine.

A strong Linux, Windows, and macOS background will also help when extracting the features and behavior of malware with tools such as Cuckoo Sandbox and its cloud implementation, Malwr. (Update 09/26/2017): Here are some interesting links for going back-and forth from a pentester position to a responder position --

- http://digitalizedwarfare.com/2016/03/24/sandbox-stories-flight-of-the-great-cuckoo-bird/
- https://infosecspeakeasy.org/t/howto-build-a-cuckoo-sandbox/27
- https://bdavis-cybersecurity.blogspot.com/2016/12/cuckoo-sandbox-installation-part-4-of-4.html
- https://byte-atlas.blogspot.com/2017/02/hardening-vbox-win7x64.html
- https://github.com/AlicanAkyol/sems
- https://github.com/hfiref0x/VBoxHardenedLoader
- https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser (N.B., benchmark your defenses with some attacks!!!)
- https://github.com/a0rtega/pafish

Most-importantly, learning DFIR has aided at improving my pentesting tradecraft as well. If I know what to detect, then I know how to counter that detection! For example, the course I recently took at the DerbyCon Training: Advanced PowerShell for Blue and Red Teams -- helped quite significantly for hiding shares (but then detecting them with the MountPoints2 registry key) but then using other protocols such as WMI, WinRM, or PS Remoting to hide in plain sight on the network.

Learning some forensics techniques has also helped my pentesting in a variety of ways. For example, the other week I used a network-block device userland server (nbd-server) to access a disk remotely with the nbd driver and nbd-client in order to run a localized cvechecker.

Get the two books: Learning Network Forensics, and also, Windows Malware Analysis Essentials. Practice using the -- https://github.com/jonschipp/ISLET -- training environments, especially with Bro. There are many great resources but these will fast-track you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes absolutely. As penetration testing approaches becoming Red Teaming at the higher end this type of skill and the ability to create tools which can exploit sites and maintain persistence becomes almost mandatory. I understand that most penetration testers on the market today probably don't have these skills but as that field continues to evolve and mature they will need to know more and more.

More importantly, I would tell you to dive deep into the areas of security that interest you because a lot of the job titles like "penetration tester" may go away in time and become something else.

At a high level, the question you are asking is would my having a second skill help me in my career. The answer is yes as long as this is not a distraction away from the primary skill. In your scenario, this doesn't sound like the case at all so go for it.

Finally, if you are in college it doesn't hurt to find a mentor who's an expert in the field you want to be in and seek out their advice. They may tell you many things about that career path which could be worth gold to you that you aren't even experienced enough to think about yet. Never rely solely on a college curriculum to determine what you want to learn either, follow the technology you love. Dive deep and do projects on your own too.